# No module named - Python

Tags: python, api

Olá,
Fiz a instalação do mailchimp3 dessa forma:

```
pip install mailchimp3
```

E também do mailchimp:

```
pip install mailchimp
```

Não apresentaram nenhum erro.

Quando vou executar o códio no python:

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp

client = MailChimp('YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY')
client.lists.members.all('YOUR_LIST_ID', get_all=True, fields="members.email_address")
```

Retorna o erro:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'mailchimp3'

Alguem já passou por isso? Obrigado!

Comment: É bem provável que o ambiente python que o pip instalou as libs não é o mesmo que o código está sendo executado.
Tentou fazer tudo isso em uma virtualenv? Se fez, conferiu se a env foi ativada com `source bin/activate` ?

Comment: Olá @fernandosavio, eu comecei a pouco tempo a usar o python. O que é uma virtualenv? Estou usando o Anaconda Navigator e executando o código através do VSCode.

Comment: Você instalou também a versão 2 do MailChimp após a instalação da versão 3, remova-a com "pip uninstall mailchimp" e reinstale a versão 3.

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com o Anaconda Navigator, provavelmente você precisa utilizar ele pra escolher o ambiente de desenvolvimento correto ([docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/getting-started/)).

Comment: @GiovanniNunes Muito obrigado! Resolveu o problema.

Comment: Vou transformar meu comentário em resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você instalou também a versão 2 do **MailChimp** após a instalação da versão 3, remova-a com `pip uninstall mailchimp` e reinstale a versão 3.